# Python: Getting "ValueError: Cannot open console input buffer for writing" when trying to to write to a file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6

I'm expanding a PyQt application we use for internal debug. One new functionality is to write a XML with some definition. I have reused code I used in other projects. I made a button which calls the writing function.

```
...
pstr = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ", encoding='utf-8')
with open(xml_fn, mode="wb") as wf:
     wf.write(pstr)
```

When calling this I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\software\appear_tool\python3tools\fwcom_gui_lib\core.py", line 616, in save_xml
 with open(xml_fn, mode="wb") as wf:
 ValueError: Cannot open console input buffer for writing
```

I tried to look for the error, but I found nothing on that. Any idea what I could be doing wrong ?
I'm running the application on Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you want wb mode with xml?

Comment: What is the `xml_fn` variable? The error message indicates that you are trying to write to the console input buffer.

Comment: xml_fn is the file name, which is defined longer up.
It doesn't matter if I use `mode='w'` or mode `mode='wb'`. The error should come in the next line in this case.
How can I end writing the to the input buffer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out what was the problem:
The function was called from a QtPushButton: `qt_button.clicked.connect(self.myclass.save)`. The save function had was defined `save_xml(self, xml_fn=None)`. When calling from clicked, it passed a boolean which ended in the xml_fn. This boolean was used as a filename in `open()`, leading to that cryptic error.

Comment: The error results from passing a boolean to `open()` instead of a file path is what I needed